# flutter json_serializable tojson does not work properly

Tags: flutter, json-serialization

Im looking into the [Order](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/example/lib/example.g.dart) class example and found that the Item class is not converted to Map.

```
class Order {
  int count;
  int itemNumber;
  bool isRushed;
  Item item; 
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$OrderToJson(this);
}
```

The generated .g file has this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> _$OrderToJson(Order instance) {
  ...
  writeNotNull('item', instance.item);
  ...
  return val;
}
```

The item in order map is still of Item type, but Im expecting it to be auto converted to Map as well. the generated .g file should has something like this

```
writeNotNull('item', instance.item.toJson());
```

I don't want to manually add this since it will be overwritten when .g file is regenerated. Why is the json_serializable lib not doing such a simple thing, or am I missing something? thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now I found the solution, just set this in build.yaml

explicit_to_json = true.

and regenerate the .g file. It should convert it to Map for you now.

Answer (score 8):

For firebase you'll want the `any_map` option also since the maps from firebase are `<dynamic, dynamic>` otherwise it will expect `<String, dynamic>`

Create this file as `build.yaml` in the root of your flutter project, it doesn't exist by default.

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable:
        options:
          any_map: true
          explicit_to_json: true
```

Comment: why is the explicit_to_json needed ? Why is the default false ?

Answer (score 2):

`json.encode(...)` will attempt to find a `toJson()` method on the `Item` class, and serialize the item correctly. There is no need for the generated serialization logic to call `toJson()`.

You just have to make sure that the `Item` class is also annotated with `@JsonSerializable()` and implements `toJson()`.

---

Also, you would never call `toJson()` manually, instead you pass your order object to `json.encode(...)`

Comment: thanks for your reply @boformer, i do understand encode will convert it correctly but what im looking for is a returned map whereas encode returns a json String. the firestore lib that Im using expect the datas to be of Map type, so I will have to use decode again to convert it back to Map type. I think if .g file should use instance.item.toJson() to save us the extra effort.

Comment: In that case you probably have to write the serialization code yourself

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below line above your child-level data model class... So it will call in dept toJson method of each model...

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
```